# Send command request to router and get its reply programatically

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, ipv6

My project requires to identify whether the connected routers in the network supports IPv6. With loads of hours searching on the internet I found out that the following command,

root@linuxrouter:/# `test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "Running kernel is IPv6 ready"`

can be used in order to find the IPv6 ready status of Linux kernel routers. My query is, is there a way to do this problematically from a remote Linux box within the same network? where the user could execute application in which the application would send  the request to the router (user inputs/ hard codes the IP of the target device) and obtain the "Running kernel is IPv6 ready" reply from the router to the application?

Any reference material or code segments from you experts will be very much appreciated as I am new to this field. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you know the router's MAC address? [IPv6 link-local addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6)

Comment: You need the device's MAC address to have any chance of doing this remotely. And if you have that, then you can just ping its expected link-local address. Of course this won't necessarily answer the question; your device may be IPv6-capable but the functionality disabled.

Comment: @anthony-arnold yes sir..obtaining the mac address is possible :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see what you mean there sir :) I will check more what you said :)

Comment: See @MichaelHampton's comment. Pinging the link local address of the router is a quick way to see if IPv6 is on.

Comment: @anthony-arnold What if packet filtering is enabled as well and pings are swallowed?

Comment: Then you're out of luck and need something more involved. Opening a socket could also work.

Comment: hmmm...i will see about the suggestions you made :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you need is reported through the pseudo-file you mentioned. Thus, you will need a remote shell access to query it (or, remote filesystem access of sort, but that's basically the same thing).

The situation is roughly identical on Windows, btw: while Windows has all kinds of fancy data reporting network APIs you still need to provide (local/domain) user credentials to access those.

As to how to establish a remote shell connection programmatically, you've got multiple options, libssh being a handy one: http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_command.html

There's also an SNMP route, but unless you've got an existing working SNMP setup on your machines it's hardly worth the trouble (and secure SNMP connections require comprehensive authentication and TLS context, so ssh is definitely a much simpler approach).

Comment: Thank you very much :) i will check on this :)

Comment: Your suggestion seems a good method sir! the issue I am having is the libssh2 will diplay the results for commands like `ifconfig` or `uptime` which has a default out put. However, the command I am submitting returns a customized output via an `echo` and that result does not get displayed when I run the application. :( do you know how to fix this? the example I utilized to test libssh2 was - http://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2_exec.html .Thank you very much sir

Comment: Try running something like this `/bin/bash -c "test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo \"Running kernel is IPv6 ready\""` on the remote side.

Comment: Thanks for the tip sir..checking your solution right now :)